# setTimeout - a imagem não fixa na tela (p5.js)

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Programando em javascript/p5.js

Estou tentando usar a função setTimeout, mas a imagem, quando acionada, fica piscando na tela, não fixa. A ideia é que a elipse apareça depois de determinado tempo, e permaneça. Primeiro achei que fosse algum bug no meu código, então limpei tudo até ficar apenas a função setTimeout e ainda assim apresenta o mesmo comportamento. Seria isso um problema do p5.js ou o quê?

```
function setup() {
createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);    
}

function draw(){

background(25);

function ball(){
stroke(255);
noFill();
ellipse(200, 200, 50, 50);
}

setTimeout(ball, 2000);

}
```

---

obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poderia tentar assim:

```
function setup() {
createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

var reload = false;

function draw() {

background(25);

function ball() {
    stroke(255);
    noFill();
    ellipse(200, 200, 50, 50);
    reload = true;
}

if (!reload) {
    setTimeout(ball, 2000);
}

}
```

Comment: Ainda continua instável. É por causa do Draw function, que passa o background por cima em cada ciclo. Se eu colocar o background no setup function e a ellipse depois disso, ela fixa.

Mas o problema é que é um jogo, outras formas se movimentam na tela e depois de um tempo aparece esse círculo. Então o background tem que estar no draw function mesmo.

obrigado

Answer (score 0):

A partir do que Heathcliff disse, encontrei essa solução: o setTimeout acionar o true, e dentro de uma condição if == true, desenhar a ellipse

---

```
var ball = false;

function setup() {
createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
background(25);

setTimeout(delay, 3000);

function delay(){
ball = true;
}

if (ball)
{
fill(255);
ellipse(200, 200, 50, 50);
}
}
```

---

obrigado!